# fixed size column with a second column responsive (fixed margin between columns)

Tags: html, css, layout, less

Is there a way to have a 2 column layout that handles the following conditions:

1. the first column has a `max-width`, and `min-width`
2. the second column has a fixed `margin` (20px for example) and which is with should be the rest of the layout free space?

This pretends to be a responsive layout that keeps margin and a sidebar between the defined values.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after a `div` `display:table/table-cell` layout, **[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/82hhq/1/)** (*[visual clarity here](http://jsfiddle.net/82hhq/2/)*)

nb. if you want the sidebar/content to stick to 100% height, add `position:fixed;` to the `body`

CSS

```
body, .viewport{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.viewport{
    display:table;
}
.sidebar, .content{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.sidebar{
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:300px;
    width:300px;
}
.content{
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='viewport'>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        content
    </div>
</div>
```